# Check if term preceeding keyword is a number

Tags: regex, r

Given a String:

3 Design Features

, I'm trying to check if the term preceeding "Design Features" is a number or not using the below. (The number can exist as 2 or 2.)

```
score=0;
str = <P>3 Design Features</P>
regexp_number =  "/^[0-9]+./";
if(str_detect(y,regexp_number) ==TRUE)
 {
   score=score++;  
 }
```

This returns 0. What am I doing wrong here? Hoping someone can point out?

Thanks in advance.
-Simak

Comment: Is actually it R code ?

Comment: @agstudy  `score = score++` and `str= <P> 3 design .. <P>` without quotes...It's look like a mix of R and pseudo-code to me

Comment: @dickoa indeed... I misread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. It says it must contain a `.` to match, rather than optionally contain 0 or 1 `.`.
Change it to

```
regexp_number =  "/^[0-9]+.?/";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
w <- "aghj 3 Design Features kjkl"
x <- "aghj 3. Design Features kjkl"
y <- "aghj c Design Features kjkl"
z <- "4 aghj c gn Features kjkl"

fun <- function(x) grepl("[[:digit:]]",
                         regmatches(x,
                                    regexpr(".\\.?(?= Design Features)",x,perl = TRUE)))


fun(w)
[1] TRUE

fun(x)
[1] TRUE

fun(y)
[1] FALSE

fun(z)
[1] logical(0)
```